# Idiot developer unable to import files dynamically in nodejs with esm modules

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, node.js-fs

I am trying to convert my commonjs repo to ESM and have having issues with the `readFileSync` command. It seems that I get different behaviour on node 18 and on node 20. I try to load a path:

`D:\dev\ts-command-line-args\README.MD`

and I get an error:

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'd:'

I then give it a path with a schema in by:

```
    const markdownPath = pathToFileURL(resolve(args.markdownPath)).href;
    console.log(`Loading existing file from '${chalk.blue(markdownPath)}'`);
    const markdownFileContent = readFileSync(markdownPath).toString();
```

and I then get this error on node 18:

```
Loading existing file from 'file:///D:/dev/ts-command-line-args/README.MD'

node:fs:601
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file:///D:/dev/ts-command-line-args/README.MD'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at writeMarkdown (file:///D:/dev/ts-command-line-args/dist/write-markdown.js:15:33)
    at file:///D:/dev/ts-command-line-args/dist/write-markdown.js:46:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'file:///D:/dev/ts-command-line-args/README.MD'
}
```

(the file definitely exists)

and this error on node 20:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\dev\ts-command-line-args\file:\D:\dev\ts-command-line-args\README.MD'
```

To further complicate this my project has already loaded a file using a pretty much identical method:

```
        console.log(`Loading args from file ${resolve(parsedArgs[options.loadFromFileArg])}`);

        const configFromFile: Partial<Record<keyof T, any>> = JSON.parse(
            readFileSync(resolve(parsedArgs[options.loadFromFileArg])).toString(),
        );
```

> Loading args from file D:\dev\ts-command-line-args\package.json

this working code is in `parse.js`. I am running this code with:

> node dist/write-markdown

`write-markdown.js` imports `parse.js`:

```js
import { parse } from './parse.js';
```

So it seems (this is an assumption) that loading files in js files that are run directly by node does not work but loading files in js files that imported does work...

I really hope that someone can clear this up for me!

Comment: `ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME` sounds more like you used `import` with the path. The `ENOENT` happens because the `fs` API should not get a scheme, only a regular path. What is `resolve` exactly? Note that there are different functions from different modules called `resolve` doing different things, such as `path.resolve` and `url.resolve`.

Comment: resolve just resolves the path. Turns "readme.md" into D:\dev\whatever\readme.md. I fixed the ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME by adding a schema into the url. That then gave me other errors.

Comment: You are not showing the whole code. `ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME` can't come from `readFileSync`. It may come from `resolve` in case you use the wrong `resolve` (like maybe `import.meta.resolve` instead of `path.resolve`), that's why I'm asking. Please show the full code of `write-markdown.js` or at least a **reproducible** example.

Comment: the code is here:
https://github.com/Roaders/ts-command-line-args/blob/main/src/write-markdown.ts#L16
I am 95% the error is coming from readFileSync (but of course I don't know why it's not working so I may be wrong). To run the code: npm run build && npm run verify-markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were chasing a red herring. It's always important to check the stack of an error and see where it's coming from!

The full stack for your `ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME` error was this:

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1078:11)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1158:3)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:318:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:404:22)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:106:35)
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
    at loadArgConfig (file:///C:/Users/david/Temp/ts-command-line-args/dist/helpers/markdown.helper.js:121:23)
    at file:///C:/Users/david/Temp/ts-command-line-args/dist/helpers/markdown.helper.js:114:42 {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}
```

The important part is:

```
at loadArgConfig (file:///C:/Users/david/Temp/ts-command-line-args/dist/helpers/markdown.helper.js:121:23)
```

...which refers to this code:

```js
export async function loadArgConfig(jsFile: string, importName: string): Promise<UsageGuideConfig | undefined> {
    const jsPath = join(process.cwd(), jsFile);
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
    const jsExports = await import(jsPath); // <------------------- ERROR HERE!!!

    const argConfig: UsageGuideConfig = jsExports[importName];

    if (argConfig == null) {
        console.warn(`Could not import ArgumentConfig named '${importName}' from jsFile '${jsFile}'`);
        return undefined;
    }

    return argConfig;
}
```

It has nothing to do with the `write-markdown.ts` file and its usage of `readFileSync`! You changed code in that other file though, which changed the error because you introduced a new bug instead, in code that runs *before* this one, so it now failed earlier.

The solution is to keep the code related to `readFileSync` as it was because it worked just fine (without `pathToFileURL`) and instead use `pathToFileURL` in `loadArgConfig` (the place the error complained about):

```js
const jsExports = await import(pathToFileURL(jsPath).href);
```

See my pull request https://github.com/Roaders/ts-command-line-args/pull/45

Comment: Many many thanks! I've not actually tried your solution yet but it makes total sense.